# Class vs Function to Define an IndexedDB Store in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, class, indexeddb

As you will see from my question, I am new to TypeScript/JavaScript.  I am working on a Blazor Wasm app that uses an IndexedDB.  I notice that there are these 2 (and no doubt more) ways to create objects for the database's store.  I'd like to know what, if anything, favors one approach versus the other.  Clearly, the function approach is much more succinct.  But the class approach seems conceptually better.

```
class myObject
{
    _property1: string;
    _property2: number;

    constructor(parm1, parm2)
    {
        this.property1 = parm1;
        this.property2 = parm2;
    }

    get property1() { return this._property1; }
    set property1(value1) { this._property1 = value1; }

    get property2() { return this._property2; }
    set property2(value2) { this._property2 = value2; }
}

function myObject(parm1, parm2)
{
    return { property1: parm1, property2: parm2 };
}
```

Comment: The class with all these setters and getters that do nothing but to recursively call themselves doesn't even work. Use the simpler approach. There is nothing "conceptually better". You can still switch later should you find a need for features that require `class` syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the edit :-) But the getters and setters are still pointless. Use normal data properties unless you need special behaviour!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classes are serializable but in doing so functions are dropped. To recreate the class after a read, you need to double every read operation. indexedDB will load the data in non-class form, and then you will need to create the class and then copy the data into the class members using something like `Object.assign`. You can get away without the copy provided that you use `function.call` style syntax everywhere, but even that will have issues if methods access `this`.

It is a giant mess. Just do not do it. Just work with plain objects, e.g. "data".

Other languages have nice efficient facilities for coercing the serialized data back into a class, as in, deserialization. Javascript does not. All you  accomplish by doing this class read/write stuff in javascript is making your program needlessly slow.

#### type assertion example at zero cost

```js
function loadObject(db: IDBDatabase, id: number) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   const txn = db.transaction('store');
   const store = txn.objectStore('store');
   const request = store.get(id);
   request.onsuccess = event => resolve(event.target.result);
   request.onerror = event => reject(event.target.error);
  });
}

interface MyObject {
  id: number;
  _property1: string;
  _property2: number;
}

function isMyObject(value: any): value is MyObject {
  return typeof values === 'object' && value !== null && 
    Number.isInteger(value.id) and typeof value._property1 === 'string'
      && 'etc...';
}

async function loadObjectWithTypeAssertion(db, id) {
  // Load object as type 'any'
  const object = await loadObject(db, id);

  // Prove to the typescript compiler that the 'any' type 
  // is in fact an instance of the 'MyObject' type
  if (!isMyObject(object)) {
    throw new Error('object loaded from db is not type MyObject');
  }

  // At this point because we are after the type assertion call,
  // object is now type "MyObject" in intellisense
  // Thefore the return type of this async function is now 
  // Promise<MyObject>

  return object;
}
```

#### Object.assign example

Pretend functions in previous example still around.

```js
class MyObject() {
  private _property1: string;
  private _property2: number;
}

async function loadAndAssign(...) {
  const object = loadObject(...);

  // Create an empty instance of MyObject
  const myObject = new MyObject();

  // Copy the data loaded from db into the instance
  Object.assign(myObject, object);  

  // Now the "myObject" instance has props

  return myObject;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Josh and Bergi.  I am coming from a c# paradigm where the class approach is great because of the strong typing.  While I've read about javascript's dynamic objects, I was thinking that TypeScript would give me the c# strong typing on data coming from the IndexedDB without the "mess."  Your responses to my question have opened my eyes.  Bummer.

Comment: I seem to be able to simplify the class using property names (e.g. "BBName: string") and a constructor that assigns those properties.  I can then instantiate an object when I want to create a new one to add to the IndexedDB, while simply typing any variables I assign with records that come from the database (e.g. "let idbRecord: MyObject = event.target.result;").  The latter lets Visual Studio's Intellisense assist me with the possible property names as I'm coding and ensures pre-compile strong typing. Am I missing anything else?  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you are missing something in the sense that what you are doing to achieve intellisense type information has real cost. You can instead use a TypeScript type assertion to recognize an any type object loaded from the database as an instance of a specific TypeScript interface without any real processing cost.

Comment: In addition, using a constructor that copies input into properties is just another reinvention of the wheel. `Object.assign` is a standard library function in javascript for exactly this purpose and it removes the need for the boilerplate.

Comment: Josh - Thanks once again.  (1) I have used TS type assertion, which is fine if there aren't a number of references to the same object, in which case it seems better to just define the type of the object in the idbRecord assignment.  Regardless, none of it affects the JS code TS generates as I understand it. This is only a pre-compile question. (2) I like the Object.assign idea.